# Ignore response body in Gatling

Tags: scala, memory, gatling

As part of a load test in Gatling, I download a huge file (about 4GB).

When doing so, I can observe the memory usage of Gatling gradually increase, until it hits 2GB, when it stops the download until it times out.

As I don't care about the response body (as long as it's being downloaded), I'd like to discard it.

How is this possible?

I'm not sure a code example is useful, but this is the calling exec:

```scala
exec(
  http("Get image data")
    .get("Url/To/Data")
    // Don't save the response body, as it's too large
    // .check(bodyString.saveAs("responseBody"))
    .check(status.is(200))
)
```

Comment: When you say you _don't care about the response body as long as it's being downloaded_, you mean that you still want the download to finish completely, that is download the 4GB? Or would it be ok to "cancel" the request once the headers are received and you get a HTTP 200 status?

Comment: The download needs to finish completely (otherwise the server won't receive enough load).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response body will not be consolidated and will be discarded unless:

- you do use it, eg with a check
- you enable debug logging that causes it to be displayed in the logs

Comment: Note that debug logging only causes it to be displayed when the request fails. For that to work it needs to be saved anyway though, so disabling debug logging helped.